# Update only the same value on all of Key Setting with whereIn

Tags: laravel

I want to set up value like this:

```
ID KEY VALUE
1  site_name 
2  site_title
```

And i use this:

> In My Update Function

```
$keys = ['site_title', 'site_name']
$values = [
        ['value' => $request->get('value')],
        ['value' => $request->get('value')],
        ['value' => $request->get('value')]
    ];
 $setting = Setting:: whereIn('key', $keys)->update($values);

    return 'Update';
```

Then it's give me a error about SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'.
Can anyone help me please!
Thank so much

Comment: First Change wherein with whereIn.

Comment: and field names are in the capital characters.

Comment: Thanks. It's a first i use stackoverflow so seem like the error come to review code. Thank so much

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = [
        ['value' => $request->get('value')],
        ['value' => $request->get('value')],
        ['value' => $request->get('value')]
    ];
```

Which is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 'some value'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 'some value'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 'some value'
        )

)
```

Check the  ***mass updates section*** in update method in the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates

The **update method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated.**

So when you put this in the update, it picks up `0` from here and tries to update the column `0` with the value as the corresponding array.

So if you want to update the `value` column in the table.
You need to have it like this

```
$data = [
     'value' => 'value that you want to pass'
];
```

and then do the update

```
$setting = Setting::whereIn('key', $keys)->update($data);
```

Comment: Thank for reply. But somehow i do with this: 
$data = [
     'value' => 'value that you want to pass'
]
It's will update on value to all key in my database. I'm looking forward to find how can update with one key -> one value but not use loop.

Comment: First you check whereIn condition how many record match .

$setting = Setting::whereIn('key', $keys)->get();

Comment: `It's will update on value to all key in my database. I'm looking forward to find how can update with one key -> one value but not use loop. ` Can you explain this, or maybe add an expected outcome in the post, that would really help. And yes the solution i gave will update that value for all the keys that you have. I thought that is what you wanted. And if you want to update different value for each $key but you want to use update just once. I can help you with that. Let me know if you want to do that or if I mis understood your question :)